# Spin.js , append div (with absolute position) and spin it

Tags: javascript

I'm using [Spin.js](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/)

What I would do is this: "append" a div (with absolute position) to another main-div and active Spin on it.

### Javascript Code

```
s+="<div style='position:relative;margin-top:"+obj.top+"px;margin-left:"+obj.left+"px;width:180px;height:70px;background-image:url(img.png);' oggetto='1' id='id1'>";
    s+="</div>";

$("#miodiv").append(s).spin();
```

### Html result of Append

```
<div style="position:absolute;margin-top:365px;margin-left:470px;width:180px;height:70px;background-image:url(img.png);" oggetto="1" id="id1"></div>
```

The Spin is add to the div but not in the center , but in the middle of the page.

I've seen questions like this on SO ([...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23843817/insert-the-spin-js-spinner-into-a-div)), which gave as a solution adding *position:relative* to the div, but I have to keep *position:absolute*.

Also if from the console of google chrome call:

```
$("#id1").spin();
```

the spin is successfully added to the center of div

### UPDATE

Added [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nicolomonili/5y0tkt2s/), which represents in a simplified way my situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give to your dynamically created div an id (lets say spinContainer) and add the spinner like this:

```
var spinner = new Spinner().spin($("#spinContainer"));
```

You also have a problem with your code here:

```
s+="<div style='position:relative;margin-top:"+obj.top+"px;margin-left:"+obj.left+"px;width:180px;height:70px;background-image:url(img.png);' oggetto='1' id='"+passid+"'>";
    s+="</div>";

$("#"+passid).append(s).spin();
```

In the first line you creating a div with id = passid

and here `$("#"+passid).append(s).spin()` you appending this div to some other element with the same id...

EDIT: 
Check the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5y0tkt2s/1/) - you supposed to add the spin to the div that you dynamically create and not to the parent div.

Comment: (code correct). this don't work var spinner = new Spinner().spin($("#spinContainer"));

Comment: the problem is certainly the position:absolute of my div

Comment: i have added jsfiddle

Comment: Check the fiddle i just added !